# How and when to use registerBestMatchingNetworkCallback introduced in Android API 31?

Tags: android, kotlin, streaming, wifi, android-connectivitymanager

I wanted to connect to wifi from app.

I was looking in to ConnectivityManager docs and came across [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerBestMatchingNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) method.

```
public void registerBestMatchingNetworkCallback (NetworkRequest request, 
            ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback, 
            Handler handler)
```

but i don't know how to use this method correctly, though i have search for it and found nothing.
specifically how should I pass the parameters?